# certain specific action/event handler per dynamically autogenerated panels

Tags: c#, database

I have a panel on the other half of the screen and another half for flowlayout panel that dynamically creates a panel that contains several labels, that is filled by a datatable using "for loops" question is how do I add mouseclick event for each panel that when I click one of the autogenerated panel on the flowlayoutpanel that all label.Text is transferred to the first panel... basically add specific mouseclick action for each autogenerated panel?

Comment: flowlayout panel has limited properties and event.  I prefer to use a panel class and make my own array of panels.   The panel class has a lot more properties and events.

Comment: It heavily depends on the Display Technology: WinForms, WPF/UWP, ASP.Net, other. Most GUI Elements tend to have "Tag" property that can take any object. Using the Events sender and casting, you should be able to get to said tag. And thus identify wich "line" it is. However there might be better patterns avalible, and in particular for WPF/UWP I would stringly. advise against it